# Pods fail to install

Tags: swift, xcode, terminal, cocoapods

I am trying to install pods for my project, but it fails with this error

[!] /bin/bash -c
set -e
sh build.sh cocoapods-setup

WARNING: The active Xcode command line tools, as returned by 'xcode-select -p', are not from Xcode.
The newest version of Xcode will be used instead.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleVersion", Does Not Exist

Comment: What is your Xcode version?

Comment: @Dilan its 12.5.1

Comment: Can you provide all the steps you have taken, and where you get this error.

Comment: @sasquatch I navigate to the Xcode project and run pod install in terminal , then I will see the pod name appearing in terminal after that the error will appear and no xcworkspace have been created

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

This will install the command line tools.

You can also get it from here:
[Apple Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) and install it.